# Form designer for Facebook Messenger apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm a veteran programmer, however I am new to the Facebook Messenger API.  I have seen that the API does support buttons as per this code snippet from the Facebook developers web site that uses a CURL example to demonstrate the formatting code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"What do you want to do next?",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com",
            "title":"Show Website"
          },
          {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Start Chatting",
            "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

This looks like typical JSON to me.  Is there a GUI tool that can design these layout elements, not only for buttons, but for any other Facebook Messenger form template elements that may also exist in the API?  Something that uses a drag and drop or other GUI interface that then generates the necessary JSON code or fragment to represent the designed form?

If so, please leave its name or a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Platform Design Kit for [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/design-resources/design-kit

Comment: Thanks!  Are you a Facebook Messenger app developer?  If so, are there any known areas of the api/sdk where: 1) The docs are really bad or wrong, and 2) There are know bugs or problem areas I should watch out for and work around?

Comment: Pretty much accurate afaik. There's also a lot of good third-party guides around for various features and getting started

Comment: "There's also a lot of good third-party guides around for various features and getting started" - Thanks.  Do you have any favorites that you refer to often?